# Backbone.js global events

Tags: backbone.js

A quick question regarding Events in Backbone - is there any way to define a set of global events, which can be re-used in different views?

For instance - say I have several Views which are rendered on the page. Each View has a button that will expand a menu. There are also several other generic elements and events. Without putting this event logic into each View, is there a way that each of these Views could inherit, or pull these events from a global events definition? It would certainly save time and be a lot cleaner solution by defining these generic events in one place.

I've seen terms such as Event Aggregator and Factory patterns thrown around - but not sure on the best approach (or if they will achieve what I'm after).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're basically describing an event aggregator or dispatcher, yes. I've got a couple of articles on building and using them with Backbone:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/

And there are plenty more articles around the web for doing the same with Backbone and other pub/sub libraries.

It's quite simple to do in Backbone:

```
vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

and now you have a `vent` object that can be used as an event aggregator throughout all of your application's views and other objects.

```
vent.on("some:event", function(){
  console.log("some event was fired");
});

vent.trigger("some:event");
```

Comment: I've come across your excellent post about it and thought it was the most elegant solution (the revisited more so)! I've followed your article and its working just fine - great article by the way. However, this still means that I need to specify the group of events in each View (which simply trigger the needed events). As each of these groups of Views always perform the same task (an add or edit button for example), is there any way to simplify the Views any futher?

Comment: FYI, looks like your lostechies.com domain is automatically redirecting to https, but it's trying to load the GitHub code snippets over http and getting blocked.