# accessing a backbone application i did not create

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a plugin to be used with a backbone application (https://smartpodcastplayer.com/). I unfortunately don't have any experience with backbone, so i have been hitting my head against the wall all afternoon:-)

My question:
Given the Backbone object, how can i get the list of all the model instance that have been created? My end goal is to listen for certain event that those object send.

i.e.: this app creates track objects, how can i get the list of all tracks starting at the backbone object.

Any alternate solution is also welcome...

Thanks!

Comment: You need to extend backbone models prototype, and require the users of your plugin to add it before their own application logic.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone object is the object provided by Backbone.js for us to create views and collections .etc. Usually, we don't assign any data to Backbone Object(depend's on implementation but mostly no).I think it's not possible to get data from models and collections given the Backbone object.

The ideal way of implementing is using events.You can listen to all the events triggered by backbone models,collections, and views and maintain the state in your plugin.This is possible only if the app triggers all the events.I can't think any other way.

Comment: Interesting idea. How would i go about listening to events, given that i don't have the objects?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042124/backbone-js-global-events

Comment: Thx, this describe how to create a vent and the app that i'm trying to hook into has a vent already in place. Is there a way for me to access it from the backbone object?

Comment: are you able to listen to the events

Comment: Sorry, i don't know much about backbone yet. What would be a good way to know if i can listen to them or not?

Comment: vent.on("some:event", function(){
  console.log("some event was fired");
}); some thing like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115789/discussion-between-otusweb-and-thunderbird).